# New Service Worker Update in Production

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am facing an issue regarding service worker update. I have deployed my code on production now we have some changes in service worker, after changes have been done when i deploy on production, i am not getting any changes made on device.

Please help me

On continuation of above problem...

After spending some time on this issue what i have done, i put a version in url of serviceworker in a queryParam e.g. main page- var workerVersion = 'v1' and registered with sw.js?ver=workerVersion.

Now on page load i checked the previous registered version with getRegistration() method if version is different then first unregister the existing worker and install new worker with latest version.

Is there any better way of doing this??

Comment: Could you share your code? There should be a cache name in your service worker. When you need to move to a new version you change the name and this should trigger a change to the new version. What happened when you tested this scenario originally?

Comment: No i can't share the code but yes i have changed the cache names, what i am doing i am importing another .js file from service worker, in that importscript js i have all the implementation, that importScript file is not updating

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this section](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#update-a-service-worker)?
Also, are you using `self.skipWaiting()` inside the install event? If not it maybe that the new version is waiting until the page is closed.

Comment: Yes i am using self.skipWaiting() inside install event of service worker, still not updating my serviceWorker